# Combining Key-Value Pairs from two Dictionaries

Tags: python-2.7

I have two dictionaries that I would like to correlate key-value pairs.

For example:

```
a_dict = [a:1, b:1, c:2, d:3]

b_dict = [z:1, xy:2, gf:4, fd:4]
```

How could I go about combining them to print as follows:

```
a, 1, z, 1

b, 1, xy, 2

c, 2, gf, 4

d, 3, fd, 4
```

Logic I used to get the key-value pairs for the dicts:

```
a_dict = dict()
for i in file:
    a = i.split("|")[3]
    if a in a_dict.keys():
        a_dict[a] += 1
    else:
        a_dict[a] = 1

for a in a_dict.keys():
    b_dict = dict()
    for i in file:
        if a not in i:
            continue
        else:
            b = i.split("|")[5]
            if b in b_dict.keys():
                b_dict[b] += 1
            else:
                b_dict[b] = 1
```

Comment: What is the logic that determines how the items from the dictionaries match up with each other? Python's `dict`s are inherently unordered, so unless you don't care about how they match up, you can't rely on the iteration order. Should they be ordered by value? If so, do you care about the order of equal value (e.g. can `b` come before `a` or `fd` before `gf`)?

Comment: Thank you for your timely response, I have edited my question to reflect how I attained the keys, values for each dictionary.

Comment: Even with the edit, it's not clear what you're trying to do. Dictionaries are unordered, so how do you want to combine the keys? In your example, just because `a` is the first key in your instantiation of `dict1`, it doesn't mean (in general) that the first item in `dict1.keys()` will be `a`

Comment: I realized the dict names weren't the same so I edited it, the keys attained for both dict are essentially the same line of data separated by a "|". I am wondering if there is a way to print key, value(count of key), key, value(count of key) with correlation between the keys

Comment: @ClamSnorkel, ...pinging you here because your other question is deleted: I wouldn't advise using *either* `shlex.split()` or `shell=True`; instead, pass an explicit argument list already split into elements. BTW, to avoid the misunderstandings that resulted in that question's reception, try to ensure that your code samples meet the [mcve] definition. If you'd provided code invoking `/bin/echo "run job %s"`, for instance, that would actually be complete and verifiable -- ie. something other people could run to see your problem themselves or test their answers.

Comment: (Above comment, and this one, will self-destruct in ~8 hours -- enough time to make sure they're read, but not polluting an unrelated question for *too* much longer than need be).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as the comments have said, dictionaries are unordered. If you want to combine the keys where order matters (i.e. the first key you inserted in `a_dict` should match with the first key you inserted in `b_dict`), you need to use an `OrderedDict`. So, you would need to change `a_dict` and `b_dict` to be `OrderedDict` objects when you read in from your file(s). Here's an example of how to print the keys how you're asking:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

a_dict = OrderedDict()
b_dict = OrderedDict()

a_dict["a"] = 1
a_dict["b"] = 1
a_dict["c"] = 2
a_dict["d"] = 3

b_dict["z"] = 1
b_dict["xy"] = 2
b_dict["gf"] = 4
b_dict["fd"] = 4

for a_key, b_key in zip(a_dict, b_dict):
    print a_key, ", ", a_dict[a_key], ", ", b_key, ", ", b_dict[b_key]
```

outputs:

```
a ,  1 ,  z ,  1
b ,  1 ,  xy ,  2
c ,  2 ,  gf ,  4
d ,  3 ,  fd ,  4
```

Observe that this will not *always* work with normal dictionaries (although it *may* depending on the keys). Change the above answer to initialize `a_dict` and `b_dict` like so:

```
a_dict = dict()
b_dict = dict()
```

and you will probably see a different output where the keys don't match up. My console gives me:

```
a ,  1 ,  xy ,  2
c ,  2 ,  gf ,  4
b ,  1 ,  z ,  1
d ,  3 ,  fd ,  4
```

**Moral of the story**: don't use a `dict` when order matters. They are simply key value stores, the order of their keys is arbitrary.

Comment: Well that explains a lot, thank you very much for your response!

Answer (score 0):

Step 1) Convert them into a list.

```
dict1=dict1.items()
dict2=dict2.items()
```

Step 2) Loop through them as so (assuming both dict (now lists) are the same size):

```
for i in range(len(dict1)):
>print(dict1[i][0]，dict1[i][1],dict2[i][0]，
dict1[i][1])
```

I apologise for the formatting since i am doing this on my phone.

NB > = tab

Edit: i cannot verify if this works since i am not sitting in front of my computer.